# Same results from Database

Tags: php

I need to add "Last member topics" in the members profile, so that it shows the last 5 topics that member wrote.

I used this code:

```
$last_topic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " .prefix. "TOPICS WHERE T_AUTHOR = '".$ProMemberID."' ORDER BY T_DATE DESC LIMIT 5") or die (mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_num_rows($last_topic);
if ($result > 0){
$rslast = mysql_fetch_array($last_topic);
$topic_id = $rslast['TOPIC_ID'];
$topic_subject = $rslast['T_SUBJECT'];
$topic_mes = $rslast['T_MESSAGE'];
$t_ret = $rslast['T_ENUM'];
$i=0;
   while ($i < $result){

echo '<tr>
  <td colSpan="2" align="center" class="userdetails_data" width="100%">
  <table border="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td>

  <font style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial"><a href="index.php?mode=t&t='.$topic_id.'">
  '.$topic_subject.'</a> 
    </td>
    <td  class="editedby" width="130">
    <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 9pt"> Edited 
    : 
    '.$t_ret.'</font></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
 </tr> 
 ';  



    ++$i;

  }

}else {
echo '<tr><td colSpan="2" align="center" class="userdetails_data" width="100%">
  <span lang="ar-eg">
  <font color="#FF0000" style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial">This member has no topics yet! </font></span></td></tr>';
}
```

It works, but showing the same topic in the 5 rows??!!

any solutions?

Comment: You need a `while` loop with `mysql_fetch_array()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting same value because your `$result` var has total rows from query which in this case is 5 while  you are saving the value to variable `$rslast`, instead use while loop so that you can loop over array values.

```
$last_topic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " .prefix. "TOPICS WHERE T_AUTHOR = '".$ProMemberID."' ORDER BY T_DATE DESC LIMIT 5") or die (mysql_error());
$result = mysql_num_rows($last_topic);

if ($result > 0){
   while($rslast = mysql_fetch_array($last_topic,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   //^-----while Loop added to loop through arrays, ^----associative array
     $topic_id = $rslast['TOPIC_ID'];
     $topic_subject = $rslast['T_SUBJECT'];
     $topic_mes = $rslast['T_MESSAGE'];
     $t_ret = $rslast['T_ENUM'];

     echo '<tr>
     <td colSpan="2" align="center" class="userdetails_data" width="100%">
       <table border="0" width="100%">
       <tr>
       <td>

       <font style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial"><a href="index.php?mode=t&t='.$topic_id.'">
  '.$topic_subject.'</a> 
       </td>
       <td  class="editedby" width="130">
       <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 9pt"> Edited :'.$t_ret.'</font></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
   </tr>';        
 }}else {

echo '<tr><td colSpan="2" align="center" class="userdetails_data" width="100%">
  <span lang="ar-eg">
  <font color="#FF0000" style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial">This member has no topics yet! </font></span></td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its because you are assigning a $rslast one time and then using this variable in loop ,

try this

```
                $last_topic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " .prefix. "TOPICS WHERE T_AUTHOR = '".$ProMemberID."' ORDER BY T_DATE DESC LIMIT 5") or die (mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_num_rows($last_topic);
            if ($result > 0){
                while($rslast = mysql_fetch_array($last_topic)) {


            $topic_id = $rslast['TOPIC_ID'];
            $topic_subject = $rslast['T_SUBJECT'];
            $topic_mes = $rslast['T_MESSAGE'];
            $t_ret = $rslast['T_ENUM'];
            echo '<tr>
              <td colSpan="2" align="center" class="userdetails_data" width="100%">
              <table border="0" width="100%">
               <tr>
               <td>

              <font style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial"><a href="index.php?mode=t&t='.$topic_id.'">
              '.$topic_subject.'</a> 
                </td>
                <td  class="editedby" width="130">
                <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 9pt"> Edited 
                : 
                '.$t_ret.'</font></td>
               </tr>
              </table>
              </td>
             </tr> 
             ';  


            }

            }else {
            echo '<tr><td colSpan="2" align="center" class="userdetails_data" width="100%">
              <span lang="ar-eg">
              <font color="#FF0000" style="font-size: 9pt" face="Arial">This member has no topics yet! </font></span></td></tr>';
            }
```